# SMTP server setup on windows xp, IIS

Tags: smtp, newsreader

I have my domain registered with godaddy. I want to send newsletter to my customers (around 5000). But there is limit to send number of emails per day.

1. Can i setup SMTP server on my home PC (windows XP) for sending these mails.
2. Is there any "open source"/Free newsletter management application (build on ASP.NET, so that i can customize it if needed) which track bounce emails and other analytics.
3. Any issue which i have to take care.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this against your ISP's policy you risk being branded as a spammer. Even with your own SMTP, the mail is still coming from your IP address, so your ISP knows all about it.

There are many bulk mail sites that will happily do this service for you, without you taking any risk. Unfortunately, they are all commercial.

As regarding a newsletter management application, you might have a look at [phplist](http://www.phplist.com/) :

> phplist is an open-source newsletter
>   manager. phplist is free to download,
>   install and use, and is easy to
>   integrate with any website.
>
> phplist's 30+ feature set includes:
>
> - double opt-in subscription mechanism
> - scheduling
> - RSS
> - list segmentation
> - click-tracking
> - attachments
> - bounce management

As a PHP application, it requires its own server. You might have a look at renting a cloud server for it, which will also avoid the bulk-mail limitations by your ISP.